# Multiple Domain pointing to single rails app displaying different content with the same url path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have searched around the web and there are answers that have helped me abit, however I am still stuck, so here goes.

I a Rails 4 app that allows users to create a biography/blog and then access it using their own domain.

Users can choose from several pre-made website templates (main page, about me page, my hobbies page, etc...), and then they load up their content using a CMS. The content will then be displayed using their chosen template when visitors visit their domain.

Eg:

**User 1:**

Domain: www.user1.com

Template: Template A

**User 2:**

Domain: www.user2.com

Template: Template B

**Desired Results**

When a visitor visits www.user1.com, they will see the main page. When they click on "About Me", they will be redirect to www.user1.com/about-me. If a visitor visits the "About Me" page for user 2, they will see www.user2.com/about-me.

My question here is, how do I set this up?

Based on this answer: [Rails routing to handle multiple domains on single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207657/rails-routing-to-handle-multiple-domains-on-single-application)

```
class Domain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.domain.present? && request.domain != "mydomain.com"
  end
end

------in routes.rb------

require 'subdomain'
constraints(Domain) do
  match '/' => 'blogs#show'
end
```

I know I can route a different domain compared to mine to a separate controller, however, I need to route it to different template controllers which can change at any moment (users can change templates at will).

I know I can set up a general controller that can read incoming requests, then based on the hostname, I can extract the appropriate template and then redirect the request to that template's controller (eg: Template1Controller), however the url gets messed up, becoming something like "/template/template1/index" or "/template/template1/about-me" which is very bad and ugly. Furthermore, it will be extremely tricky to handle paths specific to only some templates (Template A might have a "My Resume" page while template B might have a "Family History" page instead).

Is there a way to do this?

I have thought about a method where I have a single controller that will handle everything (without redirects) and then just calls `render template1/index`, but I think it is a bad way of doing it (different template might need different data in each page).

Btw, this will be hosted on EC2.

**EDIT**
What I am looking to implement is quite similar to this question [Mapping multiple domain names to different resources in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958662/mapping-multiple-domain-names-to-different-resources-in-a-rails-app) , but unfortunately no answers then. Im hoping 5 years later, someone might know how to get this done.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end to find a proper answer to your need?

Answer (score 0):

I do this pretty simple with Heroku. It's probably not hard anywhere.

Once you have DNS set up.. the Rails layer can look like...

1. Create a before_filter in ApplicationController. `before_filter :domain_check`
2. In my `domain_check` method I just have `if request.host ~= /whatever/ do this elsif ... elsif ... end`

"do this" can be a redirect or a render or whatever.